# Creating an array of numbers that sum to a given number

Tags: python

I've been working on some quick and dirty scripts for doing some of my chemistry homework, and one of them iterates through lists of a constant length where all the elements sum to a given constant.  For each, I check if they meet some additional criteria and tack them on to another list.

I figured out a way to meet the sum criteria, but it looks *horrendous*, and I'm sure there's some type of teachable moment here:

```
# iterate through all 11-element lists where the elements sum to 8.
for a in range(8+1):
 for b in range(8-a+1):
  for c in range(8-a-b+1):
   for d in range(8-a-b-c+1):
    for e in range(8-a-b-c-d+1):
     for f in range(8-a-b-c-d-e+1):
      for g in range(8-a-b-c-d-e-f+1):
       for h in range(8-a-b-c-d-e-f-g+1):
        for i in range(8-a-b-c-d-e-f-g-h+1):
         for j in range(8-a-b-c-d-e-f-g-h-i+1):
            k = 8-(a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h+i+j)
            x = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k]
            # see if x works for what I want
```

Comment: `[vals for vals in itertools.product(range(8), repeat=11) if sum(vals) == 8]` is more beautiful, but **much** slower than your solution.

Comment: +1 - Props for using a computer to automate your repetitive chemistry homework.

Comment: My insight is this: for a list of 11 integers all summing to 8, a LOT of the numbers are going to be zero. A fast way of doing this would be to find all the ways of summing integers to 8 - for example `8, 1+7, 2+6, 3+5, 4+4, 1+1+6, 1+2+5...` and then just permute those with the appropriate number of zeroes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a recursive generator that yields the lists in lexicographic order. Leaving `exact` as `True` gives the requested result where every sum==limit; setting `exact` to `False` gives all lists with 0 <= sum <= limit. The recursion takes advantage of this option to produce the intermediate results.

```
def lists_with_sum(length, limit, exact=True):
    if length:
        for l in lists_with_sum(length-1, limit, False):
            gap = limit-sum(l)
            for i in range(gap if exact else 0, gap+1):
                yield l + [i]
    else:
        yield []
```

Answer (score 1):

Generic, recursive solution:

```
def get_lists_with_sum(length, my_sum):
    if my_sum == 0:
        return [[0 for _ in range(length)]]

    if not length:
        return [[]]
    elif length == 1:
        return [[my_sum]]
    else:
        lists = []
        for i in range(my_sum+1):
            rest = my_sum - i
            sublists = get_lists_with_sum(length-1, rest)
            for sl in sublists:
                sl.insert(0, i)
                lists.append(sl)

    return lists

print get_lists_with_sum(11, 8)
```

Comment: Just tried running that. Oh my, that's slow...

Maybe convert to something that uses a stack instead of full-blown recursion?

Comment: It's targeted at low values, of course. For the given numbers, i think it's acceptable. Building a cache into it will probably help, because the arguments will repeat quite often. Still the number of possible combinations will explode for higher valued arguments.

Comment: With arguments `8,11` it redlined my CPU for a good few minutes before I killed it. OP's answer is actually very fast (just *ugly*.)

Comment: And yes, memoizing it would probably help immensely.

Comment: Hurp. I must have done something funny (I tried the lazy man's way of running it from an interactive Python shell.) I'll try it again when I get to work tomorrow.