# Is there a more efficient way to find all combinations of 10 items in 10% increments?

Tags: python, loops, combinations

I have 10 currencies I am analysing, and I want to find all possible combinations of these currencies in 10% increments. For example:

```
10% of A, 20% of B...etc
```

The constraints are as follows:

The total has to sum to 100%
There can be any amount of each currency between 0% and 100%, so a combination of 100% of A is valid

At the moment my code looks like this:

```
for element in itertools.product(*curr_arr):
    if round(sum(element),1)==1:
        comb_input.append(list(element))
```

Where curr_arr is essentially an array as follows:

```
  [0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1.0]
```

This approach is very slow because it looks at all combinations then extracts the ones that sum to one. Is there a more efficient way to do this and speed up my code?

Comment: If possible, work with percentage (10, 20, 30, …) instead of floats (0.1, 0.2, 0.3, …). These floats don't really sum to 1.0.: `0.3+0.3+0.3+0.1` returns `0.99999999999999989`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is ugly, but it is **fast**:

```
combinations = []
for a in xrange(11):
    for b in xrange(11-a):
        for c in xrange(11-a-b):
            for d in xrange(11-a-b-c):
                for e in xrange(11-a-b-c-d):
                    for f in xrange(11-a-b-c-d-e):
                        for g in xrange(11-a-b-c-d-e-f):
                            for h in xrange(11-a-b-c-d-e-f-g):
                                for i in xrange(11-a-b-c-d-e-f-g-h):
                                    j = 10-a-b-c-d-e-f-g-h-i
                                    combinations.append((a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j))
print len(combinations)
```

This gives you all your 92378 combinations in less than 0.2 sec.

Note that it returns the integer values between 0 and 10 which have to be multiplied by 10 to get percentages.

Comment: I've just tried this with range instead of xrange and each row appears to sum to 11, or 110%. Should it be xrange(10)?

Comment: @Mandeep - no, it was the 11 -> 10 in the line where `j` is calculated. Sorry for that. Fixed now. The 11 in the xranges is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Not really, your problem is basically the [Subset sum problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) (given a set of integers, find those that sum to `k`) and that problem is [NP-Complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-complete). And that means your chances of finding a significantly better algorithm than you have now are very small.

I'd recommend writing this part of the code in C as a Python extension (see [Extending and Embedding the Python Interpreter](http://docs.python.org/extending/)) and call that function from your Python code. That should give you a decent speed improvement.

Comment: Ok thanks, I guess the fastest way to solve this is to run the code once to find all combinations. Export it to excel and filter then ones that sum to 100%, then re-import those combinations each time I run the analysis

Comment: @Mandeep - you don't want to export 10**10 data entries to excel…

Answer (score 1):

How about finding all combinations which give 100% and then find all permutations of those combinations? I was unable to run your example, so I am not sure how it compares in terms of speed.

```
import itertools

curr_arr = [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]

comb_input = [a for a in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(curr_arr, 10) if sum(a) == 100]
comb_input = [set(itertools.permutations(a)) for a in comb_input]

finish = []
for a in comb_input:
    finish += list(a)

print len(finish)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for currencyA, currencyB, currencyC, currencyD, currencyE, currencyF, currencyG, currencyH, currencyI, currencyJ in itertools.permutations(range(0,101,10)):
    # you now have varying percentages of each currency
    # if sum of the currencies == 100
    # do whatever!
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to generate directly the combinations that sum to 100 %, without filtering. Using [my answer to a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9601780/222914):

```
comb_input = [[x/10.0 for x in y] for y in lists_with_sum(10, 10)]
```